# curl response is unreadble character through libcurl2 in python

Tags: python-2.7

the scenario is when using this

```
$curl --compress -ku user https://exampledomain.com/api/v1/alerts
```

the output of curl is zipped so i have to use --compress option to convert in  readable format.

I am trying to implement the same using python through urllib2

this is the code

```
import os
import getpass
import urllib2,ssl
import base64
import sys

user = os.environ['ID']
password = getpass.getpass('Enter admin password : ')

if (user and password):
    url = "https://example.com/api/v1/alerts"
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, password)).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(request,context=context)
    print resp.read()


else:
```

In return it just print unreadable character on screen.
The problem is how to convert zipped output return by curl through python code by urllib2
any help is appreciated.thanks

Comment: See the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html) module.

Comment: @glibdud from what i can understand that Zipfile has something to do with zip file on the system  not with the curl which returns content-encoding ="zip"

Comment: You indicate in your description that "the output of curl is zipped". `--compressed` is how you handle that in curl, the zipfile module is how you handle that in python.

Comment: @glibdud To make some clarification .when i used the curl without `--compress` ,the output was unreadable character and that is the same happening with current code mentioned above .when i used `--compress` in curl it gave me the desire result so i'm hoping how can i achieve this through above code.

Comment: [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) solved my problem.